# React Native Application does not run on Android, but runs after refresh

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have made a React Native App, but when I scan the QR to run the app on the person device (Android) through Expo Go, the app does not run and only the splash image is shown. The crazy part of this problem is, the app works perfectly when I scan with my iPad. Also, when I refresh the app by pulling the top bar and clicking the recycle button, it RUNS perfectly. Of course, my app works well with iOs and Android simulators. What could have caused this behavior? How should I start debugging?

Here is the link to the github repo: GitHub - https://github.com/ehayng1/myStock

What I have tried:

- Delete & Reinstalling Expo Go
- Scanning the QR with iPad (it works)

Thanks in advance!